# Displaying 24 hour format time?

Tags: java, android

In an Android app I have an internal logging method and I add a time-date stamp to the start of each message . . .

```
public void logEvent(String sMsg)  {
        String delegate = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss"; 
        java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        String sTod = " " + DateFormat.format(delegate,noteTS);
        sMsg = sTod + "   " + sMsg;
        logEvents.add(sMsg); 
 . . .
```

This produces a time-date stamp that looks like "07/25/14 02:58:18".  But I want the time to be in 24 hour format, i.e., "14:58:18".

In some systems that's accomplished by using "HH" instead of "hh" so I tried that, i.e.,

```
   String delegate = "MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss";
```

... but that just gave me "07/25/14 HH:58:18"

So what do I have to do to get the hours to be in 24-hour format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat instead of DateFormat. Refer `SimpleDateFormat` Javadoc API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
H   Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
```

"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss" should work with SimpleDateFormat.

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss");
    java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String sTod = formatter.format(noteTS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private final SimpleDateFormat sdfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");

...
TEXTVIEW.setTitle(sdfTime.format(new Date()));
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use very simple class for it.

Try this:

```
Time time=new Time();

time.setToNow();

textview.setText(time.hour+":"+time.minute);
```

Hope be useful for you.:)